# How to achieve that just the top modal window is accessible?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, radwindow

Following problem. In my application you can open multiple modal windows. Every window is dependent on the previous opened window (hierarchical). Means that when a child window is opened, the user cannot drag this child window aside and interact with the parent window.

How can I achieve, that the surface behind the top child window freezes? I use [RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radwindow-overview.html), by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was the `bool WindowBaseAutomationPeer.IsTopmost` Property of the `RadWindow` class. [Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/p_telerik_windows_controls_windowbaseautomationpeer_istopmost.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the child RadWindow's Owner property to its parent RadWindow.